# Ubuntu 20.04 boots to black screen unless I boot windows first (Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi, windows

When I turn on my computer, it shows the GRUB screen just fine, but if I select the Ubuntu option, it takes me to  a black screen. However, if I boot to windows first and then restart (not shut down and then turn back down) my computer and then select Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, it boots just fine.

So at first I assumed it was a graphics card issue because I have an NVIDIA graphics card and it seems that many other people have had issues with them. However, the issue persists even after installing the NVIDIA drivers with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460`

Next, I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763698/ubuntu-16-04-dual-boot-windows-10-boots-to-black-screen-unless-i-boot-windows-fi) ask ubuntu thread that seems to have the exact same issue as me. However, the provided solution of adding `grub_gfxpayload_linux=keep` to `/etc/default/grub` did not seem to work for either me or the OP of that thread.

I would also like to say that I have secure boot and fast boot off.

Comment: Try turning off fast boot for Windows. I had the same issue and that fixed it. Also [disable Hibernation mode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/disable-and-re-enable-hibernation)

Comment: I already have fast startup off and hibernation off. Thanks for trying tho :)